# Fourier spectrum with no peak?

Tags: fourier-analysis, contour-integration, fourier-transform

With $f(x) = e^{ik_0x} $ and the window function $W(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+a^2}$, with $a\in\mathbb{R}$, the fourier transform of $f(x)$ is given by:
$$\begin{align} F(k) &= \int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-ikx}\,W(x)\,f(x)\,dx \\
&= \int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-i(k-k_0)x}\, \frac{1}{x^2+a^2} \,dx\end{align}$$

I computed this integral using contour integration, splitting into two cases (i) $k-k_0>0$ and (ii) $k-k_0<0$, and taking appropriate contours in the lower and upper half planes respectively. I obtained: $$ F(k) = \frac{\pi e^{-(k-k_0)a}}{a} \qquad \text{for all k}\in\mathbb{R}$$

> My question is this: If I were to compute the fourier spectrum for this, I would get: $$\vert F(k)\vert^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{a^2}e^{-2(k-k_0)a}$$ which does not seem to have a peak. Does this have any physical meaning, or did I do my fourier transform wrongly? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "have a peak" ? And if $f\in L^1$ then its Fourier transform is continuous and bounded and [$\to 0$ as $k \to \infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma)

Comment: And it is easy to compute the Fourier transform of $F(k)$ and check (with the Fourier inversion theorem)  you made no mistake.

Comment: @user1952009 Typically, the power spectrum looks something like [this](http://www.gaussianwaves.com/gaussianwaves/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Power-Spectral-Density-using-FFT-how-to-plot-in-Matlab.png).

Comment: No. And did you understand what I wrote ? Is $F(k)$ bounded ? And $f(x)$ is real and even, what does it say on $F(k)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 You're saying the typical power spectrum does not have peaks? If $f(x)$ is real and even, $F(k)$ is real and even as well? But $f(x)$ is complex. So... I don't see the relevance of your last statement.

Comment: @user1952009 Also, I'm not particularly sure what result I'm expecting if I do the inverse Fourier transform. I should get $W(x)f(x)$? In this case, I don't seem to be getting that answer, so I suppose you're also implying that my $F(k)$ is wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49270/discussion-between-ksgj1-and-user1952009).

Comment: Yes $F(k)$ isn't correct. At first let $k_0 = 0$ so you are looking at the Fourier transform of $g(x) = 1/(x^2+a^2)$ with $a$ real. It is real and even, but your $F(k)$ isn't --> problem. Also $g(x)$ is integrable ($L^1$) but your $F(k)$ isn't bounded --> problem.